# Resuse ArrayList with least memory consumption

Tags: java, list, arraylist, out-of-memory

I have a List<ArrayList<String>> object in Java. The inner ArrayList<String> is of constant size.

So, while populating the List, I am using the following logic.

```
List<ArrayList<String>> map = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ....
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        list.add(/* some string */);
    }
    map.add(list);
    list.clear();
}
```

Every list inside the map is filled with null values.
Alternatively, individually instantiating the list on each loop, solves my issue, like:

```
List<ArrayList<String>> map = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ....
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        list.add(/* some string */);
    }
    map.add(list);
    //list.clear();
}
```

I have a data set of about 100,000 ArrayLists that need to be stored in the List object and I don't want to instantiate the ArrayList each time, because of the memory overhead.

So, instead of instantiating it separately, I tried one more way:

```
List<ArrayList<String>> map = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ....
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        list.add(/* some string */);
    }
    map.add(new ArrayList<String>(list));
    list.clear();
}
```

Which of these methods would give me the least memory consumption (performance is not a priority)?
If not these, is there an alternate way that this can be done more efficiently?

Comment: Sorry I did not notice you doing `new ArrayList<String>(list)` - wouldn't this add more work ?  You then need to `clear`

Comment: Except, if I don't do that the list added into the map object is also cleared to null values. I need to change the reference to the list before clearing it and the only way to do it is to instantiate it.

Comment: so code block 2 does not need to do the `clear`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you care about the memory consumption, the best you can do is call `trimToSize()` when you're done filling a list. That removes the empty capacity inside them (and requires a resize if you add an element).

You still need to use different lists, so the second way is what any sane programmer would do.

> I don't want to instantiate the ArrayList each time, because of the
>   memory overhead.

There is no memory *overhead*. You're using memory because you need to. If you want to have ~100,000 lists, you're going to have to create ~100,000 lists, end of story.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget you store pointer to object in list. not the objet itself.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ....
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        list.add(/* some string */);
    }
    map.add(list);
    list.clear();
}
```

You store a list a the *map* object then you remove everything in the list. the list in *map* is not a copy of your list! at the end, map will contains 10 times the same empty list.

In java, an array  list size will be a pointer (64bit) + 'arraysize' pointer for content + some byte for stuff. 'Arraysize' is not the content size. 
to have the less consumption, you can set arraysize to content size.

```
List<ArrayList<String>> map = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(10);
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ....
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(10);
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        list.add(/* some string */);
    }
    map.add(list);
}
```

Anyway, usually list size is nothing compared to content size.

Comment: Would the memory efficiency of the code block you've suggested and my code block 2 differ?

Comment: My last code block made the arraylist internal size match the real size it will have. So You will get a little bit less memory than if you let the capacity in automatic ( on size 10, I don't remember if capacity will be 12 or 16) so yeahhhh! great you have a 16bytes to 54bytes difference for each list.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. And both. Java is a garbage collecting language. The memory consumption has a strict upper limit set by the configuration of the JVM.

Comment: What does neither and both mean?